# Send password to administrator's window using AHK

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I am planning to enter password to command prompt (which is running as Administrator) using AHK.
But AHK fails to detect command which runs as administrator.
Here is my script which works properly if I run command prompt normally.

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
    IfWinExist, Command Prompt
    {
        WinActivate, Command Prompt
        ;enter password
        send, password
        send, {enter}

    }
```

I have changed window title to Administrator: Command Prompt, but no use.
How to solve this error ?
Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure the title of the prompt includes `Command Prompt`? What windows version are you using, by command prompt you mean cmd.exe?

Comment: If I use the word that is actually included in the command prompt title, your code works.

Comment: I have used Title as "Command Prompt" in my bat file. and I said this works in normal run. I am getting error when I run bat file as Administrator which is my requirement.

Comment: And what are the actual titles of the windows you're targeting?

Comment: I'm with @2501 - your bat file may be called "Command Prompt" but it is perhaps launching another window and that window should be identified in your script.  You can also use the ahk_class and ahk_exe (e.g., ahk_exe cmd.exe) and ahk_pid (which info you can get from a windows spy utility incl the one that comes with AHK) to define that window and some of those should give better results.

Comment: Also, be aware the admin process are shielded from the view of lower processes (see https://autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#uac) -- are you launching your AHK script with admin privileges?  You may want to have a look at https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/70449-enable-interaction-with-administrative-programs/ but proceed with caution if you do.

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment, if all you need to do is launch your ahk script as an admin, just add this code before the substantive part of your script (and make sure you read and understand this for some important limitations and qualification: https://autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#uac)

```
if not A_IsAdmin
   {
   Run *RunAs "%A_ScriptFullPath%"  ; Run as admin
   ExitApp
   }
```

Hth,

Answer (score 0):

Take note that I don't agree with this method, as it is storing a Password in plain text is a security issue, also making an assumption that your Command Prompt is cmd.exe:

```
password := "Your Password Here"

Process, Exist, cmd.exe
pid := ErrorLevel

DllCall("AttachConsole", "UInt", pid)
stdout := FileOpen("*", "w `n")

stdout.write(password)
stdout.read(0)
```